# On click Add / Remove Class and Add / Remove Values for one set of DIVs at a time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I am working on a wordpress website using Generate Press and Super forms. The website is https://ibsolutions.biz/piesarul.
The super form is used in a page called configurator to create a custom request for quotation form.
I got it to work up to the point where the user can toggle buttons and checkboxes show up based on whether the buttons are toggled on/off.
However, I want to make it so when a toggle button is on the others are off. I tried my luck with this bit of code:

```js
$(".super-toggle-switch").click(function(event){
$(this).addClass("super-active")
.siblings()
.removeClass("super-active");
});
```

It didn’t work out. Any suggestions on how to improve it?
What currently happens is that when the toggle switch is turned on, the div with the super-toggle-switch class is also assigned the class ‘super active’.
Additionally, when the button is toggled on, a subordinated div called super-shortcode-field is assigned the value “on” and when toggled off, it is assigned the value “off”.

Basically, what I am hoping to achieve is that both the value of super-shortcode-field and the class assignment are triggered for only one of the toggle buttons at a time.

Right now, the user has to toggle the buttons both on and off manually, and I want to eliminate that extra step for them.

Being at the beginning of my JS and JQuery journey, I would appreciate any and all help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery, stopped using it 7 years ago. In pure Javascript, this is very easy:

```js
const switches = document.querySelectorAll('.super-toggle-switch');
for (const switch of switches) {
    switch.addEventListener('click', toggleSwitches)
}

function toggleSwitches(event) {
    for (const switch of switches) {
        switch.classList.toggle('super-active', switch === event.target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, connexo. The solution did not work. Did you test and did it work for you? If so, I would like to see if I missed anything.

Comment: You haven't shown your HTML, so how was I supposed to test? I don't follow links to external websites in StackOverflow questions, unless they reference "official" documentation. Please create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve